# Sprockets error Sprockets::NotImplementedError: Custom asset_path helper is not implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, sprockets, precompile, rails-sprockets

I am getting the following when trying to precompile my assets locally

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

rake aborted!
Sprockets::NotImplementedError: Custom asset_path helper is not implemented

Extend your environment context with a custom method.

    environment.context_class.class_eval do
      def asset_path(path, options = {})
      end
    end
/Users/cman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@jbd-ruby2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:198:in `asset_path'
/Users/cman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@jbd-ruby2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:218:in `font_path'
/Users/cman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@jbd-ruby2.2.2/gems/font-awesome-rails-4.6.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome.css.erb:15:in `_evaluate_template'
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening - any suggestions as how to tackle would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I am able to precompile only if I add an initializer with the following:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    return ''
  end
end
```

However, if I do so, when I push to my staging environment, the glyphicons from Bootstrap have an empty path and thus don't render:

```
font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url("");src:url("") format("embedded-opentype"),url("") format("woff"),url("") format("truetype"),url("")
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I modify the initializer to the below, I get a path in my precompiles bootstrap asset for glypicons, but it is not to the precompiled Glyphicon file, it's to the non compiled asset path:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  def asset_path(path, options = {})
    #return ''
    "/assets/#{path}"
  end
end

@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");src:url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"),url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),url("/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular")
```

Here is my gemfile.lock as it relates to assets/sprockets gems:

```
bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
rails (4.2.5.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.2)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.2)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.2)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.2)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.2)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.2)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5.2)
      sprockets-rails
sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
```

Comment: Can you share the full source for a minimal working example showing the problem?  A git repo, eg.

Comment: Have you imported boostrap-sprockets as stated in the doc? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I think the Glyphicon issue is just a symptom of my specifying a custom `asset_path` initializer.  What I really need to figure out is why it's asking for that.  If I create a brand new app it doesn't ask for that on precompile.

Comment: can you show me where `asset_path` method is used in your source code?Also your gemfile please.

Comment: Could you provide a few more lines of the stack trace? It seems to me a gem versioning issue (which I'm unable to reproduce). What also strikes me is that in the stacktrace you have `sprockets-3.6.0` version but a `< 3.0` version in your `Gemfile.lock`. I can see only a single sprocket version in my `gem list`. Perhaps you might want to try updating relevant gems one by one and see if the issue goes away with some gem update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily overcome this problem. Although your current problem is more a version related problem and not sure if you bundle update properly. But there is alternative solution. Try installing the following gem:

> https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-helpers

Comment: I don't think adding another gem is the answer.  As I stated I was able to pull down my prod repo and rebuild from there one by one without any need for the custom asset helper.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue and adding the sprockets-helpers gem does resolve this issue.  Any insight as to why I would all of a sudden need it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, that the main problem is in `sprockets` version. in my rails 4.2.6 project i use `sprockets` 3.6.0, and in your `Gemfile.lock` snippet you use <3.0 version.

Just like an a test, you may update rails to 4.2.6 and try out fresh sprockets 3.6.0 + sprockets-rails 3.0.1  and fresh `sass-rails 5.0.4` and `sass 3.4.22` gem. I really do not know which one of this updates will help, but, I think it should work.

Comment: I had actually tried that as well.  I upgraded sprockets, sprockets-rails, sass-rails, sass all to the recent gems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer or not, but I wound up just pulling down my production Heroku repo and confirmed everything precompiled.  I then slowly upgraded all my gems and everything continued to precompile properly.  I guess I'll never know what caused this.  Thanks to those who contributed.

Comment: I went down a similar confusing road or removing and adding things but it turned out that the reason I was getting this error was because I had a `#include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` globally in an initializer :-/